# How to automatically update username field with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So, in my application users can change their username on their profile using [the best in place gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place), however whilst the username is changed in the text_field it isn't updated at the current_user.username field until I refresh..

Here is the relevant code of the current setup:

```
 <div class="users_about_fullinfo">
            <h3><%= current_user.name %>  <small>(<%= current_user.username %>)</small></h3>
            <p class="edit-about-text">
              <%= best_in_place current_user, :username, activator: ".edit-username", nil: 'Click here to edit your username', inner_class: 'form-control', ok_button: 'Save', ok_button_class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs creat-event blurb-ok', cancel_button: 'Cancel', cancel_button_class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs cencel-event blurb-cancel' %>
              <span class="edit-icon edit-username"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
```

Now ideally, I'd like it to work so that when a user updates his/her username the current_user.username field is updated on the spot as well, without a refresh. How might I do this?

Cheers!

Comment: add your ajax code or refresh that content function

Comment: Cheers Sridhar! That's the challenge, I'm not quite sure what the Ajax code will look like in this particular case.

Comment: You just find function that will update this html in document load,so just call that function after that request that will update the username without refresh

Comment: Thanks, it's a little vague though. Can show some examples of this pls? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the best_in_place gem, but it seems to provide a way to define your own actions which happen on the successful edit:

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#ajax-success-callback

To solve your problem you should include the user name in the field you are changing so that you can access it from the javascript:

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :name, :data => {:user_name => @user.name}, :classes => 'username-field' %>
```

And then add a javascript handler for the success callback:

```
$('.username-field').bind("ajax:success", function(){
    $('.username-in-the-header').text($(this).data('userName'));
});
```